# Jmeter - get nested Json string

Tags: json, regex, api, jmeter, automated-tests

I'm using Jmeter for API test. in one of the responses I get Json that includes the same key ("id") twice - nested and not.
this is an example of the response (part of it):

```
{
"id": "3600f05a-2ef6-490d-95af-7742f652cbfd",
"progress": 1,
"status": "done",
"task_update_time": "2016-01-24T08:23:12.274Z",
"result": {
  "id": "c8b1ed07-0b57-4473-a4d7-08f7b829aad7",
  "name": "testPrintFlow",
  "geom": {
```

now, I want to get the second (nested) "id". until now I used Regular expression extractor. I can use it also in this case, like this:

```
"result":{"id":"(.+?)"
```

but I want something more robust. I guess I can use some Json library, but I made few tries and there seem to be many holes. can someone please recommend (and explain) what is the best way? either regular expression or Json. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you used `.` ? Is `_` also part of `id` value ?

Comment: actually used it as  a default, but '-' is part of the id.

Comment: Since `.` means all characters, you might want to modify it according to permitted characters.

Comment: maybe, but that's not the point.